# Keyboard activated LED's blink out on language change

Tags: 14.04, keyboard

When I change languages on my 14.04, my keyboard's LEDs go out. For example when `Num Lock` is activated in English when I `Shift+Alt` to change language the led goes out, the function though remains (num lock is in fact activated).

This happens to both my laptop and desktop computers.

Any chance this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

In your keyboard layout settings, you can click on Options and decide about the behvior of `NumLock` button as shown on this picture (sorry, I use French language):

[image]